# Create or Update key value pairs in both maps

Tags: java, java-8

I've map of key value pairs with each value being a map of key value pairs.

Something like

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer> outMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Integer> inMap = new HashMap<>();
inMap.put("i11", 111);
inMap.put("i21", 121);
outMap.put("o1", inMap);
```

How would I handle the entry where I can create/update at both levels of the map using java 8 ?

Input would be outer key/inner key and value. So we should we able to add a new entry is it doesn't exist in outer map. If the entry exists in outer map then insert the new entry  in inner map if it doesn't exist else update the inner map with new value.

Comment: You'll have to be much more precise than that if you don't want your question to be closed very soon.

Comment: Much more context is needed. Is this about multithreaded access?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov No, its not. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: @user2683814, it that case, just make a method that strictly updates exactly as you want and call it from wherever the update happens.

Comment: `outerMap.computeIfAbsent(outerKey, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(innerKey, value)`. But of course, you could also just get the value out of the outer map, check for null, insert it, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done with this single line of code:

```
outerMap.computeIfAbsent(outerKey, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(innerKey, value)
```

But without these methods, you can achieve the same with just get() and put():

```
Map<String, Integer> innerMap = outerMap.get(outerKey);
if (innerMap == null) {
    innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    outerMap.put(outerKey, innerMap);
}
innerMap.put(innerKey, value);
```

Comment: Thank you. Nicely done. I didn't know the compute variations can return the value.

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO UPDATE THE SINGLE-VALUE AND MULTIPLE VALUES AT THE SAME TIME SIMULTANEOUSLY IN TWO MAPS**

**NTOE:**
givenMap.computIfAbsent(k,Funtion) -> if key in given map is null or absent, then compute the value using funtion and add into the given map

```
 Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> outMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> inMap = new HashMap<>();
        inMap.put("i11", 111);
        inMap.put("i21", 121);
        outMap.put("o1", inMap);

    System.out.println(outMap.toString());
    System.out.println(inMap.toString());
```

**OUTPUT BEFORE UPDATING:**

{o1={i11=111, i21=121}}

{i11=111, i21=121}

```
//If you want to add one value in the inner hashmap you created:
 outMap.computeIfAbsent("newHashMapKey",k -> new HashMap<>()).put("Arpan",2345);




// if you want to add more than 1 value at a time in the inner hashmap

   outMap.computeIfAbsent("newHashMapKey2",k -> new HashMap<>()).putAll(new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
                put("One", 1);
                put("Two", 2);
                put("Three", 3);
            }});


        System.out.println(outMap.toString());
        System.out.println(inMap.toString());
```

**OUTPUT AFTER UPDATING BOTH MAPS AT THE SAME TIME**

{o1={i11=111, i21=121}, newHashMapKey2={Two=2, Three=3, One=1}, newHashMapKey={Arpan=2345}}

{i11=111, i21=121}